# is Geocoder flutter not free like Geocoding api

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geocoding

I'm using the Flutter Geocoding Plugin library,
https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding

I'm just confused by the Geocoding APi that is on the google map service here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

is it the same? and is it paid?

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator instead of Geocoder

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede no, I think it's something different, I use both.
a geocoder to do reverse-geocoding,
and a geolocator to get a location.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the use and pricing of an off-site resource and not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the home page of the plugin [Geocoding of baseflow.com](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)

> Important:
>
> This plugin uses the free Geocoding services provided by the iOS and
> Android platforms. This means that there are restrictions to their
> use. More information can be found in the Apple documentation for iOS
> and the Google documentation for Android.
>
> The availability of the Google Play Services depends on your country.
> If your country doesn't support a connection with the Google Play
> Services, you'll need to try a VPN to establish a connection. For more
> information about how to work with Google Play Services visit the
> following link: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview

And the [Before you begin section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#before-you-begin) of the Google Maps API got this

> Before you start developing with the Geocoding API, review the
> authentication requirements (you need an API key) and the API usage
> and billing information (you need to enable billing on your project).

**So by conclusion, the first is free and the second ain't!**